# Does $M\cong N\oplus \mathbb{Z}^k$ have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $M, N$ are $\mathbb{Z}$ modules, is there a name for the condition that $M\cong N\oplus \mathbb{Z}^k$? Like "$N$ is a _____ of $M$"?

Comment: Direct summand?

Comment: that just mean $M=N\oplus P$ though

Comment: I mean specifically when $P$ is free.

Comment: @Timkinsella $N$ is a (direct) summand of $M$ with finitely generated free complement

Comment: @egreg thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does (maybe) not fully answer your question/satisfy you, but there is at least a name for something close to this, namely for free $M$ of finite rank:

An $R$-module $N$ is called stably free of rank $n-m$ if $N \oplus R^{\oplus m} \cong R^{\oplus n}$.

Otherwise you can say something like $N$ has a free complement of finite rank in $M$.